# losing style when change css file by js

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a page with style like this [image]

So I'm trying to change CSS by js when click on the button

So this is my js code

```
this.document.getElementById('style-bandle').setAttribute('href','./assets/demo/default/base/style.bundle.rtl.css');
```

so when I click on the button the CSS file changed but there is a second that I lose the style before load the new file CSS like that

[image]

After CSS load the page returns like the first image with style, How can I avoid this loading style?

Comment: Maybe you can append a new <link /> element instead of replacing it and try to override the old styles directly. But i'm not sure if this will work :)

Comment: i have tried that but if these two files are existing in same time not working correctly

Comment: create classes with style in your css file then use jquery or javascript to add those classes in your element and when not needed remove them.
consult these links
https://api.jquery.com/addclass/
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AngulerJS, you can simply make use of it and change the href of your link tag from the controller of your page :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" data-ng-if="filePath " data-ng-href="{{ filePath }}" />
```

The `ng-if` attribute is there because the script need to be executed in order to have a value in the "filePath" variable and in the meantime we hide the `<link>`. You can also try to put a default value for the href instead.

And then, for your button, you can call a function in the controller by using `ng-click` attribute instead of `onclick`.

The code in your controller should look like this :

```
myModule.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.filePath = 'pathToYourDefaultCSS.css';
   $scope.changeToDark = function() {
       $scope.filePath = './assets/demo/default/base/style.bundle.rtl.css';
   }
}]);
```

Comment: that's nice idea but i'm using angular 6 not 1 so I will search for that idea in angular 6